# API 25 Changing language in APP

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an app in Android Studio where the user can change the language.
The problem is, that two important functions are deprecated in API 25:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("eng"); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = myLocale;                             //deprecated
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);                  //deprecated
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
startActivity(refresh); 
finish();
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that without these two functions?

Comment: How about reading the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics))?

Comment: Alright thanks! Im getting the part with how locale works in api 25, but i have no idea how the part with the updateConfiguration is supposed to work in 25.

Comment: You really shouldn't include this feature. Language settings are managed by Android and should apply to all apps. By including this feature you are just making life more difficult for your users.

Comment: In other words: the user selects your apps language when he picks the language for his or her phone. You don't need to include a separate option to change the language just for your app. This will only hurt the user experience across the whole phone while at the same time needlessly increasing the complexity of your app.

Comment: Well but i have to. Its part of the assignment...

Comment: Well, im a student and i have to do this for an assignment. So i dont really have any other choice.